# Is there a way to let Ranger policy execute SHOW database?

Tags: apache-ranger

Apache Ranger : 1.2
Hive : 2.3.3

Ranger policy-A : AD Group-1 has access to both DB-1 & DB-2

Ranger policy-B : AD Group-2 has access to only DB-2

When a user1 belong to Group-1 executes "SHOW DATABASES;
he could see list of databases.

But, when a user2 belong to Group-2 does the same gets below error,

```
HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [user2] does not have [USE] privilage on [*]
```

Is this expected behavior?

Was expecting user2 should be able to see only databases he has access to when he executes "SHOW DATABASES"

Comment: Have the same problem on Hive3.1.1. Cannot show database he has access to it only. The only choices is none or show all databases.